# ASP.NET Cannot Find MySQL Host Even Though I'm Not Using MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am trying to get a simple web page up and running, which uses TreeView as well as an SiteMapDataSource. The TreeView is to list links on the web application. My data source for the site navigation is an XML file (Web.sitemap).

When I run this application in my web browser, I get the error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

It says my error is on line 285:

```
Line 283:    <siteMap>
Line 284:      <providers>
Line 285:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
Line 286:      </providers>
Line 287:    </siteMap>
```

Source File:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config    Line:  285

I am not using MySQL or any RDBMS for my sitemap, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. I did Install MySQL onto my system, as well as the plugins for Visual Studio 2015, so could this be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I applied Mcanic solution, I removed oracle MySQL .Net Connector it via Control Panel. The problem was fixed. It worked.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got the same problem in a BlogEngine site after installing another site with a  WordPress application. The installation of WordPress included the installation of MySql, and an entry in the .NET Machine.config file. This is in a Windows Server 2012 R2. You can remove the entry from the machine configuration, but that might cause problems somewhere else. I opted to add a Remove key in the BlogEngine Web.Config file.

Note: added location in configuration file.

```
<system.web>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="PageSiteMap" enabled="true">
        <providers>   
            <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
            ...
        </providers>
    </siteMap>
</system.web>
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: This is better than change the "machine.config" file, because works for everyone on the team.

Comment: Add this inside <system.web>

Answer (score 5):

Inside `<system.web>` add this;
Like this as below;

```
<system.web>
   ...
    <siteMap>
    <providers>   
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
<system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for exactly place in config!

Answer (score 4):

I followed the source file location:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config and scrolled to line 285. I deleted the MySQL data on and around this line of code.
Ran my application again, and it works fine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, "MySQL .Net Connector" was installed on our server. I removed it via Control Panel / Programs and features and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
```

this is defining a mySQL datasource, with a connectionString named LocalMySqlServer. The exception will be thrown because your app can't connect to the server defined in that connection string.

Comment: That is the weird part. That a MySQL data source is defined, even though I am not going to make use of a MySQL data source. I didn't define a MySQL data source, I specified that I am using a sitemap file which I created, on the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
<siteMap>
      <providers>
  <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

First go to the control panel remove the MYSQL CONNECTOR
**You can go >** `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config`

**Please remove the following and try this** ,

```
 <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else experiencing this issue. I installed MySql on my machine for a totally unrelated project and yet it seemed to affect another website I was working on. Adding the remove provider fixed the issue for myself