# Getting error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts." In an application that doesn't use MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

We're migrating a series of applications from older servers to new servers.

After testing this application successfully in our new DEV server and then promoting the code to the new PROD server, this is returning an error. After checking the database code in this application, I am certain we're using SQL Server and not MySQL... I'm a little puzzled as to why this would occur. Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT: I got an administrator of our server to view this error from the local machine and this is what is really being returned, specifically having to do with the sitemap providers listed on the machine.config on the server...

> **Server Error in '/DinglemeyersApplication' Application.**
>
> ---
>
> Configuration Error
>   **Description:** An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> **Parser Error Message:** Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL
>   hosts.
>
> **Source Error:**

```
 Line 274:    <siteMap> 
 Line 275:      <providers> 
 Line 276:        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"  type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web,
 Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
 connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" /> 
 Line 277:      </providers> 
 Line 278:    </siteMap>
```

> Source File:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config 
>   Line: 276 
>   ________________________________________ Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

Digging deeper to a file system log, I find the full stack trace is as follows:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to connect
>   to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
>   (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
>   line 276) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to
>   connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    at
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.GetSchemaVersion(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString,
>   NameValueCollection config)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection
>   configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
>   at System.Web.Configuration.SiteMapSection.get_ProvidersInternal()
>   at System.Web.SiteMap.Initialize()    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.get_Provider()    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource.GetHierarchicalView(String
>   viewPath)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetData(String
>   viewPath)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.DataBindItem(MenuItem
>   item)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.PerformDataBinding()    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.EnsureDataBound()    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\dinglemeyersApplication\faeebe62\5126d38e\App_Web_fi2tylhk.5.cs:line 0 
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Search at your project for "MySQL". Someone is calling MySQL driver...

Comment: X, Unfortunately that was the first thing I did, no results from the source code. I've even decompiled the dependencies and looked for any MySQL references to no results... :(

Comment: Have you checked the configuration for the Sitemap, this seems to be where the reference to MySql is. Maybe there is a `web.sitemap` file that you didn't deploy but was hanging around on the folder you deployed to, or in the IIS root folder?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've resolved this problem using the approach described in StackOverflow post:

[ASP.NET Cannot Find MySQL Host Even Though I'm Not Using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944070/asp-net-cannot-find-mysql-host-even-though-im-not-using-mysql)

Previously this application didn't have any sitemap defined in the web.config. By going into my web.config and adding a sitemap node, and then adding a `<remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider">` this has seemed to resolve the issue. I will continue to test the application after this migration, but now it's working!

in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
 ...
  <siteMap>
    <providers>   
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
    </providers>
  </siteMap>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This really saved lots of my time.. this really did a trick for me. thanks for very helpful answer.

Comment: This is exactly why I posted this question/answer in the first place. Happy to have saved someone time!!!!

Comment: I had a site that has been working unmolested for some months now. Suddenly it stopped working and adding the `<remove...>` fixed the issue. How did this suddenly become an issue?

Comment: Chuck, no idea when this cropped up. Glad it's helped you solve it though! That's the same thing with why I posted this in the first place, moving a site to a new server and bam it fails immediately. Maybe something involving IIS versions can lead to this being a problem?